# How to create Azure Data Factory Until activity that checks if API return status value?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to ADF activity to wait until API returns status value.

I have "Until" Activity called 'Check Completed Status' in Azure Data Factory.
It includes "Wait" and "Web" activities.

Web activity have "url" and method GET.

I was hoping that his configuration was enough to determine that Until loop is completed when API URL returns values.

However I'm getting error. How to complete this activity?

Until activity 'Check Completed Status' Expression is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a Boolean expression in until activity based on which it decides whether to continue or to terminate.

Sample video ;

https://youtu.be/aD3k8k5sdao